# How to tell what kind of screen sharing the user selected?

Tags: javascript, navigator, mediadevices, get-display-media

One can retrieve a stream of the users display using `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` . On some browsers I can also preselect the entire screens tab like so:

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
  // Pre-select the "Entire Screen" pane in the media picker.
  video: { displaySurface: "monitor" },
});
```

However the user is still free to pick any tab, window or screen they choose. Is there a way to find out what the user picked?